# how to get the path of the image which is in iphone gallery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, path, uiimagepickercontroller

i need to upload a image from iphone gallery ,but i am not getting the **path** of the picked image (using **image picker**)

in the image picker delegate method i am doing the following

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    NSString *strImagePath = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSString *strImagePath1 = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSLog(@"%@",strImagePath);
    NSLog(@"%@",strImagePath1);
    NSLog(@"%@",info);

}
```

and the info dictionary contains following key values

```
{
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x16adc0>";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000153&ext=PNG";
}
```

i used the value for key UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL as the image path to upload it to FTP but i couldnt upload the file, probably the path which i taking is incorrect.

**can anybody help me out how can i take the actual path of the picked image using image picker**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be it will helpful for u

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageView.image= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:png];
[webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath];
```

Comment: I am also sending image on FTP server by using this..It works perfectly for me

Comment: @Sudha Is there any way to get the path without saving it in document directory because its already saved in somewhere

Comment: @sudha i cant able to send image to ftp server please help me

Comment: @RamaniAshish check out these... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459265/open-stream-error-in-simpleftpsample-provided-in-apple-documentation/14460545#14460545         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893090/sending-data-by-ftp/14893235#14893235

Comment: is there a way doing this without duplicating the original file?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image in `NSData` and then Upload this `NSData`.

Your image in NSData

```
NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],1);
```

Or you can convert yourImage in `NSData` using

```
NSData *dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImageView.image);
```

For more read [NSData Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/)

Comment: Thanx for your answer,,but data is returing null                 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];