# Open stream error in SimpleFTPSample provided in Apple documentation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ftp, image-uploading

I want to upload images to server through ftp.

I found a [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) in apple documentation, and downloaded it.

When running the app(I'm using xcode 4.5.2, target iphone 5.0 simulator) it works fine.
I'm trying to create directory in my server through this app and succeeded.

But, when uploading the image provided in the app will result in "open stream error".
I didn't do any change in the app. Just typed the url,username and password. I think there is no issue with this, since, the directory which I specified was created succesfully.

While creating directory the url is "ftp://54.x.y.z/newfolder/"  it is created successfully.

But, while uploading the url is "ftp://54.x.y.z/TestImage1.png"

the filepath is "/var/folders/pn/8p0jc4qn70v37j58c1kwf8l80000gn/T/TestImage1.png"

url is got by appending the last component string with the ftp url which I specified.

So, what is the mistake in it?

In the fn,

```
 - (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
 { 



case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
        [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
    } break;
```

was called and displayed Stream open error.

I googled a whole day and no needed results.
Its very urgent and I even can't start a bounty for this. Please help

Comment: check your image path may be it is not properly found?

Comment: @Sudha "/var/folders/pn/8p0jc4qn70v37j58c1kwf8l80000gn/T/TestImage2.png", this the filepath and when I browse this image, it appears fine.

Comment: yes i used it many times....

Comment: which xcode are u using?

Comment: Now i am using Xcode 4.5

Comment: the directory is created successfully, but uploading brings the open stream error, what to do?

Comment: @Sudha, anyother suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
     - (void)sendDidStart
{
    // self.statusLabel.text = @"Sending";
    [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] didStartNetworkOperation];

}

- (void)updateStatus:(NSString *)statusString
{
    assert(statusString != nil);
    //self.statusLabel.text = statusString;
}

- (void)sendDidStopWithStatus:(NSString *)statusString
{
    if (statusString == nil) {
        statusString = @"Put succeeded";
    }
    [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] didStopNetworkOperation];
}

#pragma mark * Core transfer code

// This is the code that actually does the networking.

// Because buffer is declared as an array, you have to use a custom getter.  
// A synthesised getter doesn't compile.

- (uint8_t *)buffer
{
    return self->_buffer;
}

- (BOOL)isSending
{
    return (self.networkStream != nil);
}

- (void)startSend:(NSString *)filePath
{
    BOOL                    success;
    NSURL *                 url;
    NSLog(@"localFilePathforImage..:%@",localFilePathforImage);
    assert(localFilePathforImage != nil);
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localFilePathforImage]);
    assert( [localFilePathforImage.pathExtension isEqual:@"png"] || [localFilePathforImage.pathExtension isEqual:@"jpg"] );

    assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap send twice in a row!
    assert(self.fileStream == nil);         // ditto

    // First get and check the URL.

    url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:@"ftp://80.544/"];
    success = (url != nil);

    if (success) {
        // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final 
        // URL that we're going to put to.

        url = CFBridgingRelease(
                                CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, ( CFURLRef) url, ( CFStringRef) imageString , false)
                                );
        success = (url != nil);
    }

    // If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.

    if ( ! success) {
        // self.statusLabel.text = @"Invalid URL";
    }    
    else 
    {

        // Open a stream for the file we're going to send.  We do not open this stream; 
        // NSURLConnection will do it for us.

        self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:localFilePathforImage];
        assert(self.fileStream != nil);

        [self.fileStream open];

        // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

        self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                               CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, ( CFURLRef) url)
                                               );
        assert(self.networkStream != nil);

        // if ([self.usernameText.text length] != 0) {
        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"yourusername" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
        assert(success);
        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"password" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
        assert(success);
        //}

        self.networkStream.delegate = self;
        [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.networkStream open];

        // Tell the UI we're sending.

        [self sendDidStart];
    }
}

- (void)stopSendWithStatus:(NSString *)statusString
{
    if (self.networkStream != nil) {
        [self.networkStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        self.networkStream.delegate = nil;
        [self.networkStream close];
        self.networkStream = nil;
    }
    if (self.fileStream != nil) {
        [self.fileStream close];
        self.fileStream = nil;
    }
    [self sendDidStopWithStatus:statusString];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
// An NSStream delegate callback that's called when events happen on our 
// network stream.
{
#pragma unused(aStream)
    assert(aStream == self.networkStream);

    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
            [self updateStatus:@"Opened connection"];
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            assert(NO);     // should never happen for the output stream
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
            [self updateStatus:@"Sending"];

            // If we don't have any data buffered, go read the next chunk of data.

            if (self.bufferOffset == self.bufferLimit) {
                NSInteger   bytesRead;

                bytesRead = [self.fileStream read:self.buffer maxLength:sSendBufferSize];

                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    [self stopSendWithStatus:@"File read error"];
                } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
                    [self stopSendWithStatus:nil];
                } else {
                    self.bufferOffset = 0;
                    self.bufferLimit  = bytesRead;
                }
            }

            // If we're not out of data completely, send the next chunk.

            if (self.bufferOffset != self.bufferLimit) {
                NSInteger   bytesWritten;
                bytesWritten = [self.networkStream write:&self.buffer[self.bufferOffset] maxLength:self.bufferLimit - self.bufferOffset];
                assert(bytesWritten != 0);
                if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                    [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Network write error"];
                } else {
                    self.bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
                }
            }
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
            [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
            // ignore
        } break;
        default: {
            assert(NO);
        } break;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is imageString in `url = CFBridgingRelease( CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, ( CFURLRef) url, ( CFStringRef) imageString , false));`

Comment: I replaced the above line with `url = CFBridgingRelease(
    CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef) [filePath lastPathComponent], false));` still **stream open error**

Comment: you just try to pass a static image if it will upload on the server then it may be problem with your image or you can change your image with another one...

Comment: I added an image and setting the localfilepath as [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"newimage" ofType:@"jpg"]; still getting the same issue

Comment: Did you declare NSStreamDelegate in .h class

Comment: yeah send me.. I will check it

Comment: did you pass your ftp url in this line....url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:@"ftp://11.123.99.63/"];

Comment: Did you pass you host name of ftp in this line.. url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:@"ftp://22.122.12.12/"];

Comment: my localhost ftp url is 54.248.227.25, I passed it

Comment: when I create directory using this ftp url, uesrname and password, the folder name I specified was created successfully in ftp server

Comment: how do I check that my image is uploaded or not?

Comment: after startsend the fn - (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode was called in that the `case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
            [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
        } ` while debugging.

Comment: I can also see the images in ftp server using filezilla

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line before setting the networkStream delegate in PutController.m StartSend fixed the problem for me:

```
[self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode];
```

Without the above line (or with the property set to kCFBooleanTrue instead of kCFBooleanFalse), I consistently got Stream Open Error.  I only tried with one FTP server, but it doesn't seem to support passive mode which is apparently the default.

Comment: I tried to compile it on ios8 but it does not work. Always displays "Stream open error"... Has anyone been able to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue.

This is per the hosting provider.  I think the problem is that the code maybe getting confused by the "@" sign in the login name = dev@atoz.com.?

Are you using user name with @ sing ?

Comment: I have same issue, if you found any solution, please do let me know. trying this one "ftp://nssdcftp.gsfc.nasa.gov/photo_gallery/image/spacecraft/pioneer10-11.jpg" it works

Comment: yup, because my existing user name was without @ , it was works fine, but after change hosting provider it stop working.

Comment: @NAZIK , please check https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper