# Uploading to an FTP server using SimpleFTPSample

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, stream

I am trying to upload a .txt file to a server using the SimpleFTPSample code supplied by Apple.
The error is

> Sending
>
> Stream open error
>
> The error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 200.)

The error occurs in the `- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode` method, specifically:

```
    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
        NSError *theError = [aStream streamError];
        [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
        NSLog(@"The error: %@", [theError localizedDescription]);
    } break;
```

(Line 251 of PutController.m supplied by Apple and can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/PutController_m.html))

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459265/open-stream-error-in-simpleftpsample-provided-in-apple-documentation) and a couple of others like it and I am having the same problem. I have also attempted to correct the issue using the solutions in that question, without success. This includes toggling active/passive stream properties using:

```
[self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode];
```

The server address seems correct. It does require credentials and they are correct. It does allow me to login through a browser. I also have an android app which uploads to the same place. The simple FTP code supplied can:

- create a directory on the server
- create a 0 byte file on the server
- retrieve files from their default address (Apple supply the URL of an image on a NASA ftp server which can be downloaded and viewed using the app)

However, it cannot:

- download a file from the server (open stream error)
- add data to the file created (open stream error)

I am using Xcode 4.6.3 and iOS SDK 6.1.
This is reproducible with both the simulator and an iPhone 4 device.
I have access to the server administrator privileges.

Comment: You might find it easier to use [BlackRacoon](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon).

Comment: "add data to the file created (open stream error)" usually this is accepted. You can't append to file

Comment: Im not creating the file separately then appending, I mean that in the process of the upload operation the file is created but with 0 bytes.

Comment: Also I have tried BlackRaccoon and experience a (null) error when uploading, and a test download produces a 'Stream timed out with no response from server.' error