# How to get Image Path from gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I want to get the Image Path using `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` for iPhone gallery using Objective-C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the path of the image which is in iphone gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854723/how-to-get-the-path-of-the-image-which-is-in-iphone-gallery)

Comment: @WolfPack :- Same question has been asked earlier. Search before asking any question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all image information from **info** dic in **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** method. You can use **UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL** for referenceURL of selected image.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
             NSLog(@"Image Dic Description :%@",info.description);
}
```

You get below keys from it:

```
UIImagePickerControllerCropRect
UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a path and write that image in your application documents folder.

```
NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithformat:@"sample_img.png"]; // Imgae name
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
NSLog(@"Image Path=%@",pathToFile);    //This will print the path in console
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Can I get the path like say, "gallery/pics/camera/samplepic.png" - something like this?

Comment: No its not possible. check the updated answer for sample code